# Prevent inviting existing users or previously invited

Tags: android, firebase, google-app-invites

I am using AppInviteInvitation to let users invite other others for my app.  Does anyone know if there's a way from the API to prevent users from these two scenarios:

- already have the app installed
- received the invitation previously?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase App Invites does not allow you to get information on the list of users who has been invited before or already have an application in their smartphone.

I would recommend to use combination of "Firebase App Invites" and "Facebook App Invite".

Facebook App Invite take care of both the scenarios you mentioned:

1) Already have the app installed - If the user already have an app installed the users won't see your invite in their notification.

2) Received the invitation previously - If the users already received the invite before they won't receive it further after a threshold time.

But again you don't have any API to access this information, the above scenario is taken care by Facebook itself.

Answer (score 1):

Google App Invites only allows you to find out the fact that you were invited, but does not store this information anywhere. You can use the services such as Kinvey, Deployd, PushWoosh and so on, in which you can record information about the invites sent in database. So if the invited user has an installed application you can fix the invoice repayment there, and the inviting user in the application sees how many invitations he has left to send.

Comment: PS: There are several ways to identify user: you may use some personal data, ask for sign in or use random generated id. But in third case all data will be lost for user if he/she reinstall your app.